# Automated data mapping

Tags: sql, database, data-mining, data-mapping

Do you know of any library, software or language which supports **automated data mapping**.

What is it you might ask ?
Suppose I have two source tables with their schema **AND** some data instances.
Based on some data transformation requirements/definitions, 
I manually feeded a target table derived from these source tables.

Now I have :

1. some data example instances from the two source tables
2. and data in the target table.

The tool/module/language I'm looking for might return me 
a SQL query based on the source tables, which when run would give me the target table data.

*Example :*

```
SOURCE: Person
ID   FNAME    LNAME  DATE    COUNTRY
------------------------------------
1    john     doe    monday  c.2
2    john     doe    tuesday c.1

SOURCE : Country
CID   NAME
------------
c1    France     
c2    UK   


TARGET : TPerson 
// For each person, find the latest date and join with country
ID   FNAME    LNAME  DATE    COUNTRY
------------------------------------
p1    john     doe    monday  UK
```

The discovery tool might return the following  query

```
select
     "P"||Person.id, // Complex mapping Tperson.PID = concat("P",Person.PID)
    Person.Fname,
    Person.Lname,
    PErson.date,
    country.name
from
    Person 
    inner join
    (
     select 
     pid,
     min(date) as date
  from 
     Person 
  group by
      pid
   ) as P on
       Person.pid = p.pid and
   Person.date = p.date
   inner join
   Country on
       Person.COUNTRY = Country.CID
```

There's a lot of research in this field but I'm not able to find any concrete implementation.

Do you ?

Comment: Please choose more appropriate tags. no data mining here, only data mapping and databases. maybe add SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try "Gladstone Datamap" - this software can handle some complex data mapping procedures from source to target, based on your specifications. Good luck. www.gladstonedata.com

Comment: Any chance you are affiliated with this product?